# What's jQuery’s Data Method? How & Why is it used?

Tags: jquery

What's jQuery’s Data Method? How & Why is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery’s data method gives us the ability to associate arbitrary data with DOM nodes and JavaScript objects. This makes our code more concise and clean. As of jQuery 1.4.3 we also have the ability to use the method on regular JavaScript objects and listen for changes, which opens the doors to some quite interesting applications.

Check out the complete blog post here: [**jQuery's Data Method**](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/jquery-data-method/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it stores some arbitrary data in any DOM element in a safe way.

from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

the jquery data method allows you to store javascript objects or data against any HTML element, for accessing whenever you need it.

from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> The .data() method allows us to attach
>   data of any type to DOM elements in a
>   way that is safe from circular
>   references and therefore from memory
>   leaks.

Personally, I use it most to store references to timeouts. For hover menu's that have submenu timeouts that may need cancelling (to stop the fadeout), I store a reference to the timeout, using jQuery.data() on the parent element. This is a handy way of storing this value, without the need for global arrays of timeouts.